# Finding how exactly rake invoked gcc to compile c code?

Tags: c, rake, cmock

I am trying to understand how "[cmock](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/cmock)"/"[unity](http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity)" works under the hood. Both of this are using ruby rake build tool. Is there an easy way to show/log all shell commands and its option that were invoked by rake during build? I would expect to see among other bunch of (or similar):

```
gcc a.c -o a.o -Wall -g -I"some/path"
gcc b.c -o b.o -Wall -g -I"some/path"
```

edit:
Some background to the question: I do not understand (yet) how rake and cmock works. So i thought: It would be great help if I can log how other programs (mainly compiler) were invoked by rake while building provided example. This way I can see process step by step without learning too much about reke/cmock just yet. (I have tried -t option but it does not show shell commands).

Comment: you should look at the `rakefile.rb`, and `rakefile_helper.rb` files as well as the related `.yml` file

Comment: @Toby Since I do not understand (yet) how rake and cmock works i thought: It would be great help if I can log how other programs (mainly compiler) were invoked by rake. I know that if I look on the rake configuration files I can deduce with what flags gcc was called. However what I I would be missing is order and any intermediate steps/files that are then later cleaned. (Mind you that I do not know rake - I am sure the rake expert would deduce this in no time from configs)

Comment: OK. I'm no Ruby coder but; if you find the `compile` method (ln #65 in Unity's `rakefile_helper.rb`) you can see the line that  creates the `cmd_str` and one that `exectues()` it. Google tells me that printing stuff in Ruby is done with `puts()`. So add a `puts(cmd_str)` in there for your fixture and you should see the kind of output you want. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @Toby Thank you very much for suggestion - unfortunately I did not get test your approach - however if I ever will I will report result

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic issues here.

Rake doesn't really let you easily configure your compilers, and doesn't really easily let you see the "magic" it's doing behind the scenes.

I was in the same position, and found answers to both those questions.  You probably only care about the visibility issue, but I think others will want the next step ("now that I see what it's doing, how do I change it?") so I'll add them both.

First is much easier.  Rake does a bunch of build commands, and you can see them by adding "--trace", for example:

```
rake --trace compile
```

In many cases, though, you may find that rake has been asked to build a Makefile and use 'make' or 'gmake' or some other variant, you'll end up seeing in the trace output:

```
/bin/gmake install target_prefix=
```

And that gmake is running some Makefile, probably in some path like "tmp/x86_64-linux/libxml_ruby/3.2.2" or whatever matches your system, library and version you're working on.

That Makefile is generated by rake extensiontask, and usually it just uses 'gcc' and 'g++' with no path at all, which is a nightmare if you have multiple gcc installs and want to specify it.

If your rake task *does* call something like gmake or make, then you can see what commands *that* is calling by first setting the environment variable:

```
bash/sh:   export MAKE='gmake V=1'
tcsh/csh:  setenv MAKE 'gmake V=1'
```

But more importantly, if you want to specify the actual path to the compiler, things get messy.  If you look in the same (tmp/..) directory that has the Makefile you will see that it (if it was built by rake extensiontask) will have a hidden file called ".rake-compiler-siteconf.rb" (this is on Unix, I'm not completely sure what the windows paths would be).

Inside of that file you can add some patches, I actually updated my rake compiler library by adding lines to 'lib/rake/extensiontask.rb' after the lines around:

```
siteconf.puts "require 'mkmf'"
```

(and then rebuild rake-compiler) but that will change the CC/CXX settings for *any* rake that uses that gem's extensiontask.

The other option is to add it directly to the ".rake-compiler-siteconf.rb" for the library you are trying to compile and trying to do your rake build/compile again.

The lines would look like:

```
RbConfig::MAKEFILE_CONFIG['CC'] = '/my/path/to/gcc'
RbConfig::MAKEFILE_CONFIG['CXX'] = '/my/path/to/c++/or/gcc/or/g++/or/whatever'
RbConfig::MAKEFILE_CONFIG['LDSHAREDXX'] = '/my/path/to/gcc/or/ld'
$DLDFLAGS.qsub!('-Wl,--example-of-removing-flags-from-default-ld-flags')
```